# Javascript app avoid server-side languages

Tags: javascript, nginx

Have some experiments to build javascript app without support any server-side languages like php, python ... just javascript with a network database layer api. Used orchestrate.io, but the HTML5 CORS require strict headers response like *Access-Control-Allow-Origin*. Is there a way to build a kind of application stepping to DbaaS ?

For example nginx is configured to run only *www/index.html*.
We need to get *.json* data using REST API through the HTTP. This is our blog articles. JSON-P cant send http headers(?).

Who knows this ?

**Setup:**

nginx

```
server {
    ...
    root /usr/local/www
    index index.html
    ...

}
```

index.html

```
function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {

    // Check if the XMLHttpRequest object has a "withCredentials" property.
    // "withCredentials" only exists on XMLHTTPRequest2 objects.
    xhr.open(method, url, true);

  } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {

    // Otherwise, check if XDomainRequest.
    // XDomainRequest only exists in IE, and is IE's way of making CORS requests.
    xhr = new XDomainRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);

  } else {

    // Otherwise, CORS is not supported by the browser.
    xhr = null;

  }
  return xhr;
}

var xhr = createCORSRequest('GET', url);
if (!xhr) {
    throw new Error('CORS not supported');
}
xhr.withCredentials = true;
var url = 'https://api.service.io/article/1';
var xhr = createCORSRequest('GET', url);

xhr.onload = function() {
    var responseText = xhr.responseText;
    console.log(responseText);
 // process the response.
};

xhr.onerror = function() {
    console.log('There was an error!');
};

xhr.send();
```

and i need to send basic auth http headers ... thats all

Comment: I am unsure what you mean. Is this a specific issue you are having with CORS or orchestrate.io? Can you provide more information on everything you have setup?

Comment: This is not a orchestrate wishlist question. More about integrate pure javascript with DBaas. Setup is quite simple as a load html from explorer.

Comment: I am still confused. DBaas is a general term for Database-As-A-Service. Perhaps you can provide details about your setup (e.g. web server config, Javascript code example). It would really help to see some example code producing a specific error in the question.

Comment: So you want to give the world unfettered access to your database? That's the only way I can picture this playing out without a server-side frontend.

Comment: https://www.firebase.com/ https://parse.com/ etc etc.

Comment: Seems like all he's asking for is how to send cors headers for .json files with nginx. If that's the case, this question could have been a whole lot clearer.

Comment: i think the firebase is a service for such things ... and what i am asking for

Answer (score 0):

Nginx [proxy module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html) can do just that: it catches your request with an ordinary `XMLHTTPRequest` to some local (same origin) path of your choice and proxies it to a remote service adding any headers the service needs with `proxy_set_header` directive.

For example, I do proxy requests to a Mailgun service with just few lines:

```
location = /mailgun-send
{
  proxy_pass  https://api.mailgun.net/v2/mg.inshaker.ru/messages;
  proxy_set_header  'Host' 'api.mailgun.net';
  proxy_set_header  'Authorization' 'Basic YXB3lzbWJlaTVq2N1ZjJ6NG1MDh5aDd0epOmtleS0zM4NjRseXVhNw==';
}
```

and then just `$.ajax('/mailgun-send')`.